# Avoid duplicate selection using np.random.randint

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python, specially the machine learning related python. The below lines of code select some indices from the `distinct_zeros` array but it is doing duplicate selection. What should I do so that duplicates are not selected.

```
import numpy as np

distinct_zeros =np.array( [[0.17857143, 0.28571429, 0.32142857, 0.35714286, 0.35714286],
 [0.64285714, 0.60714286, 0.35714286, 0.39285714, 0.57142857 ]])


train_zero_indices = np.random.randint(low=0, high= len(distinct_zeros[0]), size= int(0.5* len(distinct_zeros[0])))
print(train_zero_indices)


   (pennylane_study) m992c693@alveo:~/RESEARCH_WORK$ python np.random.randint.py 
    [3 3]
```

**Edit**

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
train_zero_indices= rng.choice(len(distinct_zeros[0]), int(0.5* len(distinct_zeros[0])), replace=False)
print(train_zero_indices)
```

The above lines gives the correct result but there is no option to put low value in it. It is taking low as 0 by default.

Comment: `len(distinct_zeros[0])` is the length of the 1st row, did you mean it as high boundary?

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest for the response. Yes, high= len(distinct_zeros[0]) is the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) with `replace=False` (to avoid selection of a value multiple times):

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.choice(distinct_zeros.shape[1], distinct_zeros.shape[1] // 2, replace=False)
```

---

A random sample:

```
array([4, 2])
```

---

To set *low* and *high* boundaries you can pass the respective `range(low, high)` as the 1st argument. But be careful, you **cannot** request `size=3` from the `range(3, 5)` having deduplication requirement. So it remains on your conscience.

```
rng.choice(range(2, distinct_zeros.shape[1]), distinct_zeros.shape[1] // 2, replace=False)
array([3, 2])
```

Comment: rng = np.random.default_rng()
train_zero_indices= rng.choice(len(distinct_zeros[0]), int(0.5* len(distinct_zeros[0])), replace=False)
print(train_zero_indices)              Hi @RomanPerekhrest. How to put low here? Edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: do you mean `low=0` ?

Comment: The solution provided works if low is 0. But suppose i want to adjust low to some other value, then how should i edit the code if possible.  I have also edited the question.  @RomanPerekhrest.